# I want to write a Firebase Function for a different project. How do I do that?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have 2 different projects that I'm working on concurrently. I worked on the 1st project and have a native index.js file for that project. Then, I wanted to write Cloud Functions' code for the 2nd project. So, when I typed 'firebase init functions', it is saying that there's a default project that's selected (even after typing "firebase use *project-id*"). How do I rectify this?

PS: I completed the whole sequence once and the index.js file got overwritten. Luckily for me, I had a back up for the 1st project.

Edit 2: I changed directories and created a project but it overwrote the index.js file once again in the 'functions' folder. How to fix this? Should I navigate out of the home directory itself?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Configure Multiple Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/?authuser=0)

> The Web and Admin SDKs are configured by directly passing values to
> their initialization functions. For these SDK, you can use a runtime
> check to select development or production configuration variables.

On your development machine / project build out each app under a unique folder.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what my question is about!

Comment: Can't you firebase init from within each projects unique (sub)folder? ...Like initializing git in subfolders? ...That's what it looks like you are needing to do since (each projects) cloud functions take a single index.js.

Comment: But the thing is if the subholder is in the home folder, it is creating the new project by overwriting the index.js.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure to understand the problem but here are two possible scenarios:

1/ You are working in a specific project, writing Cloud Functions (i.e. modifying the index.js file) and you want to work on another totally different project. Just create a new directory (outside of the current project) and initialize a new project there, as explained in the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#initializing_a_project_directory): "https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#initializing_a_project_directory"

2/ You are working in a specific project, writing Cloud Functions (i.e. modifying the index.js file) and you want to deploy the same code to **another Firebase project**. Just do `firebase use <alias_or_project_id>` as you have mentioned and then `firebase deploy` (or `firebase deploy --only functions`). Of course, in this scenario, you may need to adapt some other parts of your code when swapping from one project to the other, like for example the JavaScript `config` object.

If this answer does not answer your problem, please give some more details.

Comment: How can it overwrite a file in the newly created `Guduapp` directory you have just created?? Not sure to understand.

Comment: It's not. It's overwriting it in the parent directory. So even if I change the path, it's creating the project in the home directory if you know what I mean.